# Using WSO2 Identity Server for managing more that one "account"

Tags: permissions, wso2, multi-tenant, wso2-identity-server

I'm exploring the WSO2 Identity server as a possible solution for a requirement we have.

We manage a lot of accounts, and every account has it's own admin users, users & roles.

We have a set of available permissions which is shared between all accounts, and (permissible) users can create new users, roles, attach roles to users etc..

But, the Users / Roles must be separated between the different accounts.

Also, accounts can be created / modified during run time.

What is the best practice to achieve this using the WSO2 IS? Maintaining User store per account? Using multi-tenancy?

I'm all over the WSO2 docs and can't seem to find a recommended solution to this requirement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is better to go with multi tenancy. There you can create multiple tenants for each group and have an admin user/users/permission/roles specific to that particular group